# SOP violation in paho mqtt

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

when I am trying to use Paho MQTT javacrript with Mosquito MQTT websockets, everything works as long as the web server that I am using to serve my page and Mosquito are in the same server (same origin). However, if I try to connect to a different Mosquito instance (cross domain), Firefox throws a security error.

Problem is that the Javascript client initiates a http connection to the Mosquito web socket server and it gets upgraded to ws:// as part of negotiation. Had the initial request itself been over ws:// , SOP would not have kicked in.

I tried to connect to the second server from http://mitsuruog.github.io/what-mqtt/ and it works fine without SOP error. So, I know that the server can support ws:// . How to get this done using the Paho implementation?

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I was trying to initiate an un-secure (ws:// instrad of wss://) while the page was itself loaded over https:// . This results in a mixed content error that is not explicitly reported by Firefox. Chrome prints a better warning and allows to temporarily bypass it as well.